# Weird Looping on ExternalLogin .net API for Google OAuth

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth

I got a help from youtube video on how to create a Google Authentication for .net projects. [Here is his video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsRyvWvo4EI), [and his documentation](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.sg/2016/12/aspnet-web-api-google-authentication.html).

I followed every step but I still get the same problem. For some reason, the ExternalLogin in the AccountController keeps looping, and when I have logged in to Google, Chrome tells me that

> accounts.google.com redirected you too many times.

How my code works at the moment:

1. Click on "Login With Google"
2. Redirected to Google for email and password
3. Enter Email and Password and click sign in
4. **ExternalLogin starts looping, Chrome says accounts.google.com redirected you too many times**

I am suspecting that the Access Token is not generated because on the getAccessToken() in GoogleAuthentication, i tried to print out the access token, but nothing was printed

Here is my code on ExternalLogin

```
   // GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
        [OverrideAuthentication]
        [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
            }

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
            }

            ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

            if (externalLogin == null)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }

            if (externalLogin.LoginProvider != provider)
            {
                Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
            }

            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider,
                externalLogin.ProviderKey));

            bool hasRegistered = user != null;

            if (hasRegistered)
            {
                Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

                 ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                    OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
                Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
                ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                Authentication.SignIn(identity);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Login.html Code

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/GoogleAuthentication.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    getAccessToken();
    $('#btnGoogleLogin').click(function () {

        window.location.href = "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44345%2FLogin.html&state=TQ9c4kctEKiEhf-2Uis05MLNPgKzzivmdKIwbQhnkrA1";

    });
```

GoogleAuthenticaion.js code

```
function getAccessToken() {

    if (location.hash) {
        if (location.hash.split('access_token=')) {
            var accessToken = location.hash.split('access_token=')[1].split('&')[0];
            alert(accessToken);
            if (accessToken) {
                isUserRegistered(accessToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
function isUserRegistered(accessToken) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Account/UserInfo',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/JSON',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.HasRegistered) {
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem('userName', response.Email);
                window.location.href = "Index.html";
            }
            else {
                signupExternalUser(accessToken);
            }
        }
    });
}
function signupExternalUser(accessToken) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Account/RegisterExternal',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        },
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = "/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44345%2FLogin.html&state=T7-tOpA7ERNeeLE8M4CHlZEubafM-I--np0ErWE372w1";
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Do you solved the problem?